# htop res & virt colors

Tags: linux, color, htop

I did some googling about htop, I found [this](http://www.deonsworld.co.za/2012/12/20/understanding-and-using-htop-monitor-system-resources/) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/180711/what-exactly-do-the-colors-in-htop-status-bars-mean).
But I couldn't seem to find what the red color of virt and res means.
As you can see in the screenshot, some are whitish and other are red.
Does it simply means allot of memory used or is it something else?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *red* color indicates that the amount of `VIRT` or `RES` memory is in the area of gigabytes. The *light blue* color corresponds to megabytes, and therefore *white* color means kilobytes.

This is, that the users has instantly a visual information, if he searches for processes, which consume a lot of memory. Notice that, the nice values (`NI`) are also red, when they differ from 0 for the same reason as above.