# What does a red swap bar mean, in htop?

Tags: linux, htop

In htop, there appear bars that show CPU, MEMORY and SWAP.

In [What exactly do the colors in htop status bars mean?](https://serverfault.com/questions/180711/what-exactly-do-the-colors-in-htop-status-bars-mean) , I saw the meaning of the colors for the CPU bar and the MEMORY bar.

What do the colors mean in the swap bar?

I could find no mention in the htop man.

Comment: swap bar doesn't have different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hitting `F1` will show this (most probably this wasn't available 7 years ago!):
[image: htop help]

Which means:

- red is used swap, that can't be removed
- orange is cached swap, that can be removed if needed

When you go out of used space, kernel will launch Out-of-memory killer (OOM killer) to free some memory (be it in RAM or Swap).

You can retrieve the Swap cached/used values with `/proc/meminfo`:

```
# grep Swap /proc/meminfo
SwapCached:       430276 kB
SwapTotal:       2097136 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
```

Answer (score 6):

The Swap Bar has only *one* colour (red) which simply indicates how much swap memory is being used. You can see this by pressing <kbd>h</kbd> (or <kbd>F1</kbd>) while running `htop`.