# htop shows 33% memory usage, but its Mem bar is full

Tags: ubuntu, memory-usage, htop

When I run `htop` on a remote computer its `Mem` bar shows that memory is full and even swap shares 2.3G(also I can see the system works very slow). But `htop`'s `MEM%` column shows about 33% memory usage. Also sum of `RES` column is about 3G which it confirms 33% memory usage. I have not any idea what is the relation between these results. Also I could not find some processes(except `PID 814`) to free memory.

You can find a screenshote from my `htop` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWjPC.png).

Another point is that `PID 814` has a red value `16.0T` in the `VIRT` column which is not clear to me(red means unit is Gbyte). Maybe changes to hugepages may affect this output. In the following you can see `cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge` output

```
AnonHugePages:    532480 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       5
HugePages_Free:        5
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB
```

*PS:* Changes to hugepages were not made by me. I do not know this influences on processes memory usage or not. (on the other hand if I roll back hugepages size, memory uses by process(es) reduces or not? How hugepages influence performance? it uses more memory but the decrease memory page faults? this memory counted as process memory usage such as its data or is respect to OS and counted somewhere else?)

Comment: You can also check /proc/slabinfo, with such a big virtual proces memory you might have most memory used in pagetables alone.

Comment: Press F1 for help

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the `htop` bar, this [link](https://serverfault.com/a/180724/405108) explains that there is a subtle color-coding in the bar itself.  I believe the first number on the right of the bar matches the **green** portion of the bar.

Regarding the bar itself appearing large, I found [this](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/) to be an interesting read.